# How do you add Apple Pay to an EAS app that uses Stripe?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, stripe-payments, applepay

In order to use my app, my users need to add a credit card # upon signing up, otherwise their account won’t work. Per App Store guidelines, apps have to be able to support Apple Pay for payments.?

I attempted to follow the steps laid out [here](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay) but it seems to only be for when he user is making a payment in real time, not storing their payment details for further use.

Below is the code for Apple Pay on stripe.

```
function PaymentScreen() {
  const { isApplePaySupported } = useApplePay();

  // ...

  const pay = async () => {
    // ...
  };

  // ...

  return (
    <View>
      {isApplePaySupported && (
        <ApplePayButton
          onPress={pay}
          type="plain"
          buttonStyle="black"
          borderRadius={4}
          style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: 50,
          }}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think you just need to use a Setup Intent instead of a Payment Intent.  This doc walks through that: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=react-native&ui=payment-sheet